# Глагол "вылыгаться" в цитате - что с ним делать? "Скорбь вылыгается из черт природы" - что эта скорбь делает, а? из черт природы, а?

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, авторская-пунктуация, архаизмы, термины

Надо ли в скобочках добавить пояснение?

И - то же ли это самое, что "[излыгаться](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/247374)" (оправдываться ложью)? Дайте, пожалуйста, лексическое значение.

Что за дикие знаки у Вересаева и должна ли я Маию оставить без "й"?

> Грек ранней стадии эллинской истории, грек гомеровский, воспринимал
>   жизнь по-аполлоновски: он смотрел на блестящий мир явлений, на то, что
>   индусы называют обманчивым покрывалом **Маии**, и принимал его за
>   подлинную жизнь. Мир этот он мыслил во множественности, в формах
>   времени и пространств, – в том, что Шопенгауэр называет *principium
>   individuationis*. «В этой форме, – говорит Шопенгауэр, – человек видит
>   не существо вещей, которое едино, а только его проявления, –
>   особенные, раздельные, бесчисленные, многоразличные, даже
>   противоположные». Человека с таким жизнеотношением Ницше, вслед за
>   Шопенгауэром, уподобляет пловцу средь бурно ревущего моря.
>   Беспредельное море, бушуя и воя, вздымает и опускает водяные горы, а
>   пловец спокойно сидит в лодке, доверяясь утлому своему суденышку, не
>   чувствуя ужаса от бушующей кругом беспредельности. Так посреди мира
>   мучений спокойно живет в своей отдельности человек, доверчиво опираясь
>   на *principium individuationis*, на восприятие жизни в формах времени
>   и пространства: безграничный мир, всюду исполненный страдания, в
>   бесконечном прошедшем, в бесконечном будущем, ему чужд, даже кажется
>   ему фантазией; действительно для него только одно – узкое настоящее,
>   ближайшие цели, замкнутые горизонты.
>
> В этой иллюзии держит человека Аполлон. Он – бог «обманчивого»
>   реального мира. Околдованный чарами солнечного бога, человек видит в
>   жизни радость, гармонию, красоту, не чувствует окружающих бездн и
>   ужасов. Страдание индивидуума Аполлон побеждает светозарным
>   прославлением вечности явления. Скорбь ***вылыгается*** из черт
>   природы. Охваченный аполлоновскою иллюзией, человек слеп к скорби и
>   страданию вселенной.

А понятно ли широкому читателю ***[principium individuationis](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/5183/Principium)***?

> Индивидуа́ция — одно из основных понятий аналитической психологии К.
>   Г. Юнга, означающее процесс становления личности, такого
>   психологического развития её, при котором реализуются индивидуальные
>   задатки и уникальные особенности человека. К. Г. Юнг проводил различие
>   между индивидуализмом и индивидуацией...
>
> ---

[Individuation](http://www.harc.ru/slovar/809.html) —

> разделение всеобщего на индивиды, на особенное. ***Принцип
>   индивидуации (principium individuationis) — основа существования
>   особей или особенного.*** С понятием индивидуации связаны две
>   проблемы:
>
> 1) почему индивидуация имеет место, почему единство действительного не
>   остаётся неделимым?  2) существовала ли индивидуация действительного с
>   самого начала, а если нет, то откуда и благодаря чему она возникла?
>
> Аристотель, так же как и Фома Аквинский, видит принцип индивидуации в
>   многообразии определённости (качественности) и состояния вещества.
>   Дунс Скот усмотрел принцип индивидуации в haecceitas. Локк и
>   Шопенгауэр считают, что принцип индивидуации мог быть данным во
>   времени и пространстве. Для Шеллинга основа индивидуации — в греховном
>   отпадении от Бога. Лейбниц считает, что мир с самого начала состоит из
>   индивидов (монад).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Скорбь вылыгается из черт природы.**

У Даля есть: Вылыгаться, отлыгаться, оправдываться ложью. [https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=вылыгаться&from=xx&to=ru&did=enc2p&stype=](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&from=xx&to=ru&did=enc2p&stype=)

От глагола ***лгать***, с приставками получаем: оболгать, изолгать (что-либо).

***Вылыгаться*** — это, вероятно, пассивная конструкция от глагола ***вылыгать*** со значением "удалять с помощью лжи".

Тогда перевод такой: **Другими словами (иначе говоря), скорбь с помощью лжи удаляется (вытесняется) из фундаментальных свойств природы.**

Так как слово совершенно не воспринимается на слух, то можно в скобках добавить пояснение.